# How to set pixel by pixel color with SDL2

Tags: sdl-2

I'm looking for an easy/fast way to do this easy thing with the SDL2, which is:
I have a Window and a renderer, I would like to set a (32bits) color for each pixel that I'm on:

for exemple I have a 5120×2880 window:

```
y = 0;
while (y < 2880)
{
    x = 0;
    while (x < 5120)
    {
        Do what ever I want with the pixel pos x, y;
        x++;
    }
    y++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ok for those who wonder it's

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, v, b, n);
SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
```

Comment: I actually was wondering what language this is. It seems kind of important.

Comment: @Jongware It is C or C++